# APK won't compile after images compressed

Tags: image, apk, filesize, shrink

I am trying to get my APK down to the size limit for Google Play which is 100mb. The easiest way for me to do this is to shrink some of the images I have. I can easily get it to about 80MB. The problem is when I overwrite the images with the new ones with the smaller file sizes, the APK then fails to compile. What might I be doing wrong?

The images are just a mix of png and jpg from the res folder. I have used various programs to mass-compress them or even tinypng.com to replace them with the smaller file sizes. Any method seems to make repackaging with apk easy tool fail.

The log says:

```
W: 
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_14601003774523830477.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 17, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 23, --version-name, 1.0.9, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL6479183413335630409.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\Matt\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\RaspIPTV_Android\res, -M, C:\Users\Matt\Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\RaspIPTV_Android\AndroidManifest.xml]
```

Comment: What's the error? How do you compress them? What format are your files? You gotta give us a little more so we can help you :)

Comment: edited my first post to include the error